# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

my register.js file

```js
const data = await fetch("/register",{
                method: "POST",
                headers:{
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    fname, email, password, cpassword
                })
            });

            const res = await data.json();
            // console.log(res.status);

            if (res.status === 201) {
                toast.success("Registration Successfully done !", {
                    position: "top-center"
                });
                setInpval({ ...inpval, fname: "", email: "", password: "", cpassword: "" });
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to register a user in my database but when i do that i got this uncaught not valid json error

Comment: you are probably getting an html back on your Ajax call. This happens sometimes when the response is a 404 or 5**. wrap the call with try and catch and handle these cases.

Comment: Can you post the `/register` end-point code?

Answer (score 1):

This error is usually associated with **pointing to the wrong URL** when performing your **CRUD** operations.

Check the **console** of your browser and it will show you where the error is emanating from, then cross-check your **URLs**, probably you have made changes to some files and have not modified certain portions of your code to reflect the changes.
**Example below:**

```
try {
  const res = await fetch('/api/create-post/new', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/ json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      prompt: post.prompt,
      userId: session?.user.id,
      tag: post.tag,
    }),
  });
```

If you're working on a NextJs application which uses a file system for its routing, for instance, you initially name your file as **create-post**, then you later change it to **post**. Your new **url** should be  **'/api/post/new** and no longer **'/api/create-post/new** as defined above in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when your data that is being fetched is not in an JSON format. To me your above code looks fine, please check what your backend is returning.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).